# The path I set for JAVA_HOME is labeled as incorect

Tags: java, hadoop

`C:\Users\dinot>hdfs namenode -format The system cannot find the path specified. Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set. Please update C:\Users\dinot\hadoop-3.2.1\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.cmd '-Dhadoop.security.logger' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

this is the error I receive

[here is the jdk folder for java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzX61.jpg)

[and here is my env variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nlSa.jpg)

This is my second try reinstalling java as it suddenly did not work, like when i tried to verify the version, it [said this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbPeu.png). java -version works now but hadoop still wont work. this is the version 3.2.1 for hadoop so hdfs namenode -format should throw an error, but not "JAVA_HOME is incorrectly"

Answer (score 0):

From your cmd screenshot, It looks "JAVA_HOME" is not expected as you set in env. Maybe it is override by some other scripts. You could verify its' value in cmd by "echo $JAVA_HOME".